# New order email confirmation not received in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, order-confirmation

In Magento I have not received any order confirmation email when I completed an Order in `Magento 1.9.1`

Comment: are you talk about.... magento new order email or order complete email

Comment: Magento new Order email notification

Answer (score 2):

Have you setup the cron job for Magento? Because beginning with `Magento 1.9` email is now processed with the Magento cron job.

Please follow through the bellow tutorial to solve your email issue.

http://adeelishfaq.com/magento-orders-email-sending-issue/

Answer (score -1):

If you have ruled out all other issues with the Cron Job, follow the steps below to fix this bug for your Magento store.

Open up the cron.php file in your Magento root directory (usually "public_html") and look for the following line of codes:-
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, ‘win’) === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;

Add the following codes in a new line exactly after the above line of codes:-
$isShellDisabled = true;

then setup a cron Job for every 5 mint

wget -O /dev/null -q http://www.domain.com/cron.php > /dev/null

All will work fine after thats